# What are the best accessibility resources?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

What are the best resources for both making sure that a website passes accessibility guidelines and for learning to build accessible websites?

Comment: Check out the accessibility-related W3C standards - go to http://w3viewer.com and click on "A"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend starting with [WebAIM](http://webaim.org) and the [W3C Web Accessibility Initiative](http://www.w3.org/WAI/)